# Run FFmpeg executable from sdcard

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

In my android application, I have to concat videos of different formats and i use FFmpeg for this.I made use of the java wrapper provided by guardianproject at the below link:

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

But this method uses the FFmpeg executable. Some of the guys suggested to avoid this approach, because we need to issue permission to run the executable s since android will not do that.

Also this can only be possible when the app's data is in phone memory.So the problem is, the app cannot be moved to sdcard. When we do so, the executable cannot be run.

I feel this method is good when compared to writing JNI. So is it possible to issue permission to a executable that can run on a sdcard.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue permissions pragmatically  to any files that resides on sd-card. Create a file object and try this

file.setExecutable(boolean); – true, allows execute, false disallows it.

I hope this works.